# Google Cloud Platform upgrade conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, updates

I would like to learn about the upgrade conditions of Google Cloud Platform's services in general : 
1) Does Google alert us with a delay (that we could fix ?) before any service upgrade ? 
2) Are unavailabilities due to Google update performed in all datacenters at the same time ? 
3) Is it possible to schedule the updates ?

I have searched a lot, and I don't find anything about that in Google's documentation for any service. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

are you asking this to know how to avoid updates from impacting your project?
as i understand the process, data centers will not be unavailable simultaneously rather the will have a rotating schedule as to back up one another.

If you have a support package or an upgraded account check out this link and see which resource will you be using and the service level agreement on each
https://cloud.google.com/terms/sla/